# Ionic 3: One header component for several pages

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm migrating from AngularJS to Angular and started to use Ionic 3 (latest) to build my app.

But I have a small problem: I want to use one header on some pages with sign out function and etc. I don't want to implement it in every component page and I want to avoid duplication of code.

I tried on my own. First of all I create separate header component

---

header.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary-light">
    <ion-title>
        Super App
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button class="button-out" icon-only (click)="signOut()">
            <ion-icon class="fa fa-sign-out"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

---

header.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

    signOut() {
        //some auth strategy and then
        this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
    }
}
```

---

The I go to pages where I want to add my header, I made `import {HeaderComponent} from './../header/header'` in `page.module.ts`, add `HeaderComponent` to `declarations` and `entryComponents` and added to page.html `<app-header></app-header>` and it was appeared.
But when I made the same into another page - I had an error:

> Failed to navigate:  Type HeaderComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: PageOneModule and PageTwoModule! Please consider moving HeaderComponent to a higher module that imports DeliveryPageModule and PageTwoModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes HeaderComponent then import that NgModule in PageOneModule and PageTwoModule.

Then I went to app.module.ts and import header there (before I removed header from page1 and page2 modules) and I've got follow error:

> Template parse errors:
>   'app-header' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]

I looked for examples but they are didn't work in Ionic 3. Can anybody to help with it or give a working manual how to do it?

Comment: Glad you want to avoid duplication, good instinct that. Generally, what you want to do is extract the header into a component. What have you tried?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I updated my question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As suggested by the error message, you want to create a shared NgModule that both declares and exports your shared header component.
For example:

**shared.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPageModule} from 'ionic-angular';
import {HeaderComponent} from './header-component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(HeaderComponent)],
  declarations: [HeaderComponent],
  exports: [HeaderComponent]
}) export class SharedModule {}
```

Then you need to import that `NgModule` in all of the modules that use it.

Consuming code will have the form

**page-one.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPageModule} from 'ionic-angular';
import {SharedModule} from './shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [IonicPageModule, SharedModule]      
}) export class PageOneModule {}
```

**page-two.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPageModule} from 'ionic-angular';
import {SharedModule} from './shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [IonicPageModule, SharedModule]      
}) export class PageTwoModule {}
```

If you want to know why Angular punishes you for correctly following your instincts to reduce duplication by creating shared constructs, that is anyone's guess.

Comment: Do as you recommended... Now I have an error: `Error: Template parse errors: 'ion-title' is not a known element` . Remove ion-title and same error again, but about ion-icon...

Comment: That means the other modules needs to import something that was previously imported by the `page.module`, likely an ionic module.

Comment: there is an IonicPageModule which bootstrapping pages in Ionic Framework. It should be imported at every module by `import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';`. And in header.module.ts it should be imported in `@NgModule` as `imports:
 [IonicPageModule.forChild(NavbarComponent)]` as well. @aluanhaddad pls add this in your answer. And thanks again! :)

Comment: @Merge-pony thanks, I updated the answer. Glad you got it working. Ionic 2 has managed to make `@NgModule` more confusing which is quite a feat.

Comment: Hi Aluan, What if I would want to create another component inside the shared directory? How do I configure IonicPageModule then?

Comment: is there any way to avoid import of NgModule and HeaderComponent in all of the modules. can we do it from app.module.ts to avoid adding in each pages

Comment: @amitgupta you can create a shared `NgModule` and import that into any modules needing it. However, you have to import that shared module into
 any module needing it.

Answer (score 0):

> **Header.html**

```html
<ion-header>
<div col-12>
    <div col-1 class="iconspace togglementopmargin" float-left>
        <ion-col width-33  >
            <button class="menubutton"  block>
                <ion-icon name="md-menu" (click)="openSideMenu()"></ion-icon><br>

            </button>
        </ion-col>
    </div>
    <div col-4 class="headertitle headertitlespace" float-left>
        {{UserName}}
      
    </div>
    <div col-2 class="iconspace" float-right end (click)="gotoadd()">
        <ion-col  class="addbtn" >
            <button class="addbtn" block >
                <ion-icon name="md-add"></ion-icon><br>
            <div>    Add</div>
            </button>
        </ion-col>

    </div>
</div>

</ion-header>
```