# Ionic: Adding Custom Header

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to add a custom header (component)

My *app.component.html*

```
<ion-app>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

When I do like this header goes on top of the content and won't take it's own space.
Also I've tried to add ion-router-outlet inside ion-content tag, but that brakes content scrolling.
How can I add custom header and not break stuff?

Comment: You should specify your ionic version! I did the same thing in the past and had to import custom component header inside every page.

Comment: Try to follow this guide
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675253/ionic-3-one-header-component-for-several-pages/43676386